# Which hand wins: 23 vs. 9J on a AAKKQ board?

Tags: texas-hold-em, rules, hand

Ignoring any flush possibility, who would win?

Board: AAKKQ

Player 1: 23
Player 2: 9J

I think both players split the pot in half because they both have two pairs and Q as kicker, but people keep trying to tell me Player 2 wins because he has J as High Card.

Is it possible for a player to win a game without using any of the cards in their hand? (Like the example before)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 16):

In Poker you use the best 5 cards, so in this case no one wins...it's split. In fact, the **only** cards that could win here are an A, K, TJ, or pocket Q's. Knowing this, even if he had JJ or even QJ, it would still be split.

Answer (score 6):

None of them. It will be a split.

Answer (score 2):

If no one uses any cards in their hands, everyone "plays the board." Then everyone (that is left after the betting) splits the pot. The way to lose in this scenario is if someone bets and you fold.

The "usual" way to win is that one or both of your cards represents an improvement on the board. In this case, if you had JT, you would make a AKQJT straight, which beats "aces over kings, queen kicker."

Answer (score 1):

You can tell the folks outright next time that in standard Hold 'Em, only the best 5 cards are playable in any one player's hand. In this case, the board is showing the best 5 cards (Aces and Kings with a Queen kicker), as neither player 1 nor player 2 can make a better 5 card hand than what is showing on the board.